# Why wasn't I ever informed that that a bounty was put on my question?

Tags: discussion, support, bug, bounties

I was wondering why an [old question of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193061/155556) was gaining steam.

I looked at it just now, and lo and behold someone has a bounty on it!

[image]

When did that happen?

Why wasn't I ever informed that that a bounty was put on my question?

Comment: And yes before anyone asks -- I did check my notifications going back a while.