# How do I retract my vote to reopen my own question closed by the RemoveDeadQuestions bot?

Tags: support, vote-to-reopen

After reading [Shog9's suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310266/303080) that simply re-asking a question closed by the RemoveDeadQuestions bot is one option, I've [done so here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33161/12102). It's previous incarnation has had my reopen vote for a while, but there's been no activity.

I think it's a good question, and it's only because of insufficient stewardship on my part that it fell by the wayside. Its [sibling question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29946/12102) did quite well and received an excellent answer.

Now I'd like to remove my vote to reopen on the dead question, but I can't. When I click the reopen button all I get is a reminder that I'd done that already, but no dialogue box to retract the vote.

What's the best way to proceed? Just ignore it (seems okay to me) or is there a magic retractyourreopenvote button I don't know about yet?

Some think that an ability to retract reopen votes [is a good idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271954/303080).

> [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no feature to retract our reopen and delete votes currently. Best way is to ignore the reopen votes on deleted questions because close and reopen votes start to expire [after a period of time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97581/357396). I believe that doesn't make a difference because you have reposted the question.

But [@animuson said the following](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271954/357396) regarding implementation of the feature asking ability to retract reopen vote and challenge from User Experience (UX) perspective.

> This would be very dangerous from a UX perspective. The dialogs would need to look very different so users don't accidentally retract their reopen votes thinking they were casting one because they forgot they already voted. With the confirmation dialog we currently use, it's not possible to modify the appearance, so simply changing the text is a horrible idea. We'd have to actually build our own dialogs for these situations in order to prevent confusion.

Comment: who am I to disagree with a "work of genius", so be it.