# Make the pop-up for retracting your delete vote different from the pop-up for casting it

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-delete, retracted-delete-votes

When voting to delete a question one gets thrown a pop-up to confirm their choice. This is in the general style of your browser.

Since recently one is also able to [retract their delete vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371279/361484).

Today I thought I was voting to delete a post, only to find out that I apparently already did so and had now retracted my delete vote.

The pop-up to delete a post looks like this:

[image: A gray pop-up that reads: "Vote to delete this post? (X votes remaining)"]

The pop-up to retract a delete vote looks like this:

[image: A gray pop-up that reads: "Retract your vote to delete? You won't be able to vote again on this post.]

Especially since users are accustomed to simply clicking OK on these pop-ups when voting to delete, one can become blind for the text in it, just like I experienced today.

#### Can something be done to better distinguish the two pop-ups?

Perhaps create them in the same way the close voting dialogue works?

Comment: ... and while they're at it, migrate it to Stacks :)

Comment: Also now [Make the "delete" button different when you already voted to delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371810/make-the-delete-button-different-when-you-already-voted-to-delete)

Comment: This has fooled me more than once in a few days - I really hope this feature request gets heard.

Comment: I keep running into this. Early in the day I'll see a post that needs deletion and cast a delete vote. Later in the day I'll see it again and Delete (2) beneath it, but I'll have forgotten I already cast a vote on it. Instead of committing a third delete vote to get the thing gone, I wind up setting it back to just Delete (1).

Comment: @doppelgreener you don't read the text in the dialog?! ;-)

Answer (score 25):

I'd go with a custom dialog, like we already have for retracting close votes and when confirming reopen votes:

[image: retract delete vote custom dialog mockup]

Comment: Pondering if it should be more explicit and say: "You won't be able to *delete* vote again on this post"...

Comment: @Jon well, took the text as-is for sake of mockup.

Comment: I know... just throwing it out there :p

Comment: Howdy make the mockups?

Comment: @VScode_fanboy developer tools of the browser.

Comment: Dialog is fine but what we *really* need is a different action link! Either the color should change once we have voted, or the text should become "Retract delete vote" or a small checkmark could be added so that you are able to tell the difference.

Comment: @MrUpsidown well action links stay the same, and it's fine. "close" link does not change after you vote to close, for example.

Comment: Yes. Which might be why I happen to click multiple times every day on the "close" link to only find out I have already close-voted a specific question. *It's fine.* - No, I don't think it is. It is bad UX. But I agree with you; both links have the same issue.

Comment: @MrUpsidown well that's worthy of a new feature request then, asking to change "close" and "delete" links once you voted to close and/or delete. I have idea in mind for how it should look like, so if you post such request let me know.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar Here we go: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418996/enhance-close-and-delete-links

Comment: Late reply here, and I fully support the concept @MrUpsidown refers to (hoping this somehow brings some attention again). *BUT*, I wouldn't go for a drastic change in the ui (link>button), rather a visual clue. I believe that it's quite important, especially considering an extremely common usage at this point in time: touch-based devices. It shouldn't change its appearance, but still I wouldn't be able to wait for its tooltip if I'm on my phone: there's no "hover", it should be an immediate visual hint. What if you just add an icon, similarly to edited comments, but only visible to the author?